# calling a multi dimensional array in php not working

Tags: php

Here is some of my PHP:

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM villages WHERE owner = ? AND id = ?');
$array = array($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['viewing']);
$query->execute($array);
$r = $query->fetch();
$r['HQlevelPlusOne'] = $r['HQlevel'] + 1;
$logsNeeded = $headquartersRequired[$r['HQlevelPlusOne'][0]];
```

the $logsNeeded doesn't seem to be working, here is the $headquartersRequired array:

```
$headquartersRequired = array(array(50,     40,     55,    30),
                              array(90,     80,     100,   80));
```

how for example would I call the value '50' ? Let's say in my current code that $r['HQlevelPlusOne'] is 1. so the value $logsNeeded should be is 90.. but it doesn't seem to be working.. Does anyone know why?

Comment: plus one cuz you are using mysqli even though you're not binding the params :)

Comment: @Prashank I'm using PDO and I am binding the parameters.. Well, I'm preparing the statements, which is still the same, I think

Comment: oops sorry i misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By numerical index, the value '50' is at index 0 of a nested array which is itself at index 0. So to retrieve it:

```
echo $headquartersRequired[0][0];
```

`$headquartersRequired[0]` points to the first index of array `$headquartersRequired`. That value is itself an array, whose elements can be accessed in the same way, so from there `$headquartersRequired[0][0]` points to the first element of the first array within `$headquartersRequired`.

If `$r['HQlevelPlusOne']` is `1` then `$headquartersRequired[$r['HQlevelPlusOne'][0]]` is wrong because `$r['HQlevelPlusOne'][0]` would reference the first element in an *array* named `$r['HQlevelPlusOne']`. But `$r['HQlevelPlusOne']` is `1` and `1` is not an array.

Comment: ah thanks! I just got a bit mixed up with the syntax, I changed to this:
$logsNeeded = $headquartersRequired[$r['HQlevelPlusOne']][0];
and now it works fine :) I was using $r['HQlevelPlusOne'] to reference the index; (I think that's what I mean)

Comment: Good, I was afraid I was going too much into details :)

Answer (score 1):

The `$r` is a single-dimensional array, but yet you are referencing the second dimension in the final line of code (`$r['HQlevelPlusOne'][0]`). That isn't going to work.

The value of 50 is located at the 0th index of the 0th dimension.

It would be in position `$headquartersRequired[0][0]` = 50.